# browser.wait() does not work when there is no spinner in ProtratorJs Test

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I am facing very weird behaviour of `browser.wait()`. In my test website sometime Spinner appear and sometime it does not appear to handle this situation I am using `browser.wait()`. But when there is no spinner appears in the page in that condition my code is not working and throwing exception. Can you please help me to resolve this issue. How I can make sure that if there is no spinner execution will continue if there is a spinner it wait for spinner to finish and then move to next step in test.

Below is my code:

```
this.waitForSpinnerFinished = () => {
        browser.wait(function() {
            return element(by.css('.spinner')).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
                return !result;
            })
        }, 30000)
    }}
```

### Bug report

Node Version: v6.10.0
Protractor Version: 4.0.9
Angular Version: 1.X
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System and Version Windows 10

- Your protractor configuration file

  ```
  require('babel-register');

  exports.config = {

      directConnect: true,
      // chrome driver location if different than installed with webdriver-manager update, when directConnect: true
      chromeDriver: './4_utilsObjects/chromedriver_2.29.exe',

      allScriptsTimeout: 180000,

      framework: 'jasmine',

          suites: {
          tests: ['1_testLaunchers/*.js'],
          visual: ['visualRegression/*.js'],
      },
       rootElement: '[ng-app="preApp"]',
           capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'chrome',
          'chromeOptions': {
              // needed to disable saving passwords in account creation tests
              'prefs': {
                  'credentials_enable_service': false,
                  'profile': {
                      'password_manager_enabled': false
                  }
              }
          },

             },

             jasmineNodeOpts: {
          silent: true,
          defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000,
          // needed for jasmine-spec-reporter
          print: function () {
          }
      },

          onPrepare: () => {
          // here we're adding real time jasmine reporter that will display test steps
          // see https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter
          var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
          // add jasmine spec reporter
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
              displayStacktrace: 'none',
              displaySuccessfulSpec: true,
              displayFailedSpec: true,
              displaySpecDuration: true,
              displaySuiteNumber: true,
              displayPendingSummary: false,
              displayPendingSpec: false
          }))

          // adding Jasmine JUnit reporter
          var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
              consolidateAll: true,
              savePath: 'reports/JUnitReporter',
              filePrefix: 'testresults'
          }))

          // reporter for TeamCity, enabled only in CI
          if (process.env.TEAMCITY_VERSION)
          {
              jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TeamCityReporter());
          }

          // Disable animations so e2e tests run faster
          var disableNgAnimate = function () {
              angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate',function ($animate) {
                  $animate.enabled(false);
              }]);
          }
          browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

          // reporter taking screenshots when failed assertion is spotted, comment out to speed up test run
          var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
              savePath: 'reports/screenshotReporter/',
              takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
          }))
      }
  }
  ```
- A relevant example test

  ```
  this.startSignUp = () => {
          element(by.css('#protractorjs')).click();
          this.waitForSpinnerFinished();
      }
  ```
- Output from running the test
- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, '.spinner')

Comment: Waiting for a spinner to be present/not present is not reliable. Instead wait for an element from the previous container to become stale or for a new element from the new container to be present.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote something in protractor so I don't have a good place to test this but does it work if you change the return in `waitForSpinnerFinished` to:

```
return result === false;
```